# Displaying database fior specefic email

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a school project a php /mysql script to show student marks 
i am done but am still having a problem in display page

Welcome.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['email'])
{

    header("Location: login.php");//redirect to login page to secure the welcome page without login access.
}
$dbservername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "e351f301005e7788";
$dbpassword = "games123";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$post_email = (!$_SESSION['email'])
$sql ="select * from student WHERE user_email='$post_email'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "username: " . $row['user_email'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Your Marks isn't ready yet";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

it keep displaying internal 500 error and i don't know the reason if any help will be apperciated 
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$post_email = (!$_SESSION['email'])
```

This line will give you a 500 error. Did you mean this?

```
$post_email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

Also in this section of your code you have more closing curly brackets than opening ones

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "username: " . $row['user_email'] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Your Marks isn't ready yet";
}
```

Comment: still same error

Comment: Yeah I spotted another error, Ill update my answer

Comment: If you look in your error logs (probably in var/log/somewhere) it should tell you which lines of your code are throwing the error. Makes it much easier to debug

Comment: Thanks so much worked :D